# Convert javascript request to an API to CURL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I was using Javascript to refresh Azure token , But now it gives me an error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So I want to use CURL(PHP) instead.

Here is the Javascript:

```
var form_data = {
    "client_id": "**",
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "resource": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
    "username": "****************",
    "password": "*****************",
    "scope": "openid",
    "client_secret": "**",
    "refresh_token": "**"
    };

    var options = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: form_data
    }

    return fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", options)
    .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
    } else {
    throw new Error("Server response wasn't OK");
    }
    })
    .then((json) => {
    return json.token;
    });
```

CURL :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$client_id = "**";
$client_secret = "**";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

How should the complete CURL request be ?

Comment: Have you tried simply including an `Origin` header on your JavaScript request, as per CORS requirements? Could be as simple as adding `"Origin": "http://your.site.xyz"` in the `headers` definition. Here's [a page with more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors).

Comment: Maybe you're running into CORS issue, since you have chosen to go PHP way then there is a library similar to javascript version called [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). You can try using that.

Comment: @GregSchmidt , I tried:
`var options = {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Origin": "http://localhost"
  },
  body: formData
  }`

Comment: But still getting the same errors:
` POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token 400 (Bad Request)

Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
ajax.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Comment: I don't have personal experience with CORS, so I don't know whether `localhost` would be a valid thing to use there. The error message mentions an opaque response option, perhaps that would work for you?